# Setting Up Multi-Server Administration---SQL Server Account

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

I am trying to set up Multi Server Administration so that I can easily update multiple instances of the same database across our network with ease. Where I am getting lost is how to set up the `SQL SERVER AGENT` service on the target machines.

Right now the SQL SERVER AGENT services on the machines are set to log on as `NTSERVICE\SQL SERVER AGENT`.

My SQL Server Agent process is set to log in as `LocalSystem`

My overall goal here is to figure out why I can't set any target servers from my machine, as I always run into the following error:

```
TITLE: Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo
------------------------------

MSX enlist failed for JobServer 'MYPC'. 

For help, click: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=15.0.18206.0+((SSMS_Rel).191029-2112)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=MSX+enlist+JobServer&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

------------------------------

The enlist operation failed (reason: SQLServerAgent Error: Unable to connect to MSX 'MYPC'.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 22026)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=14.00.2027&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=22026&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

When looking at the log on my machine I see the following error when trying to enlist the target machine:

`Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Integrated authentication.`

Comment: Did you try asking the friendly folks over at https://dba.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: @SMM I shall do that thank you for the pointer

Comment: this is not easy bro , i would like to take a team viewer to investigate into this issue , it can be many reasons , firewall issue , host.ini issue , ip issues ... etc.
the log is pointing almost same issue which is related to database connection.
no direct answer till more investigate i guss

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on the service accounts you have configured. At one point you state that it uses `NTSERVICE\SQL SERVER AGENT` but then you state "set to log in as `LocalSystem` "

From the [Docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/choose-the-right-sql-server-agent-service-account-for-multiserver-environments?WT.mc_id=DP-MVP-5001259&view=sql-server-ver15) , ***When the SQL Server Agent service is run under the Local System account, master server-target server operations are supported only if both the master server and the target server reside on the same computer.***

You mention that this is across a network, therefore you should be using Domain Accounts for your SQL Agent service

`LocalSystem` has far too many permissions to be a secure choice - especially with a MultiServer configuration where a single server compromise may open all your servers. Whenever a local or virtual account is used then the network communications occur as the Computer Domain Account  - e.g. if my server was named **s1** in the **MyDomain** then the computer account would be **MyDomain\S1$**

I recommend that you configure SQL Agent to use a dedicated domain account, following the guide for permissions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/select-an-account-for-the-sql-server-agent-service?WT.mc_id=DP-MVP-5001259&view=sql-server-ver15). Additionally, to use multiserver job processing, the SQL Server Agent service account must be a member of the msdb database role TargetServersRole on the master server. The Master Server Wizard automatically adds the service account to this role as part of the enlistment process.